# *ngFor Angular Ionic Grid population

Tags: angular, grid, ionic3, ngfor

I'm new at developing. I'm trying to draw a Row with 2 cells each contains a Category

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row *ngFor="let categorie of categories">
  <ion-col>
    <img [src]="categorie.image" />
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <img [src]="categorie.image" />
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

What I'm getting and it's kind of obvious the same category in both cells. I got like 20 categories so there should be 10 rows, 20 cells.

### Update

Abdelrhman Hussien, as per your comment, the desire outcome would be per my case:

QTY of Categories: 21 or even more

OUTCOME:
11 Rows
Each row containing 2 Categories
last Row only contains 1 category even thought you still have 2 cells in last row.

Comment: What is your desired outcome? Cells x Rows?
You can't increment Angular for by 2, but you could use ngFor with index
<ion-row *ngFor="let categorie of categories; index as i">
    </ion-row>

Comment: you are using categorie.image in the both cells so definitely it would show the same data.

Comment: you need to remap your `categories` and group it by two, outcome should be `[ [1,2], [1,2] ]`

Comment: care to explain? thanks!

Comment: I can't understand properly. If categories is 21 or any odd number then you want to show one col, you just omit 2'nd col?

Answer (score 10):

Try this code. It worked for me.

```
<ion-grid>
            <ion-row no-padding>
              <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let categorie of categories">
                      <img [src] ="categorie.image" />
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

A grid in ionic is made up of 12 columns. So if your image takes 6 columns you'll get the desired output.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#grid

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/grid/Grid/

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author).*

Thanks to commentary to group into two segments did the following.

```
    <ion-grid class="grid-categories">
    <ion-row *ngFor="let categorie of categories; let i = index" >
      <ion-col *ngIf="i % 2 == 0" >
        <img [src]="categorie.image" />
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-grid class="grid-categories">
    <ion-row *ngFor="let categorie of categories; let i = index" >
      <ion-col *ngIf="i % 2 != 0" >
        <img [src]="categorie.image" />
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

adding a litlle of ccs

```
.grid-categories {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    border: red solid;
}
```

This draws exactly how I wanted.